# Do I need a password to use RDS MySQL or do IAM roles prevent me from having to use credentials?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I'm confused by the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html). Do I still need to use a password to access MySQL in RDS?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you always need a password when accessing RDS

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, If I did not understand your question, but may be you wanted to ask... do I need to have a password to access my database in RDS using mySQL client tool?

If this is your question, then yes, you have to have a password for the schema. There is no password for "mysql" nor for "rds instance".

Basically you are connecting to the database that is residing in the RDS instance.

You can use the following command to connect to DB in RDS, you must have rds-end-point

```
mysql -h {rds-end-point} -u {user-id} -p {schema-name}
```

When you enter this command you will be asked for the password.

AWS documentation:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html